# :after selector not working if jquery inserts .active in link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-class

I'm creating a menu and once the navigation is clicked I have different image background for each stage. I'm using `:after` so I can position it absolute and place it where I want and behind the text. This is also as I'm using already `:before` for another purpose. It was working before but I was making my CSS shorter and more effictive, everything was fine except that when the link is clicked the following css selector would not work:

```
.sub-nav a:active:after, .sub-nav a.active:after
```

Once clicked and :active status is activated the image appears. Once this sector is open the jquery adds the `.active` class, but the problem is that the :after does not load.

I'm getting crazy and maybe somebody could see the error I'm doing...

Hereby you have a fiddle of my actual code:
http://jsfiddle.net/tGXWG/2/

What the :after code is inserteing is the background image like this..

:hover:

[image]

:active + .active:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that actually works? Thanks

Comment: @Giovanni Silviera I can't, thats the point, its not working. This is the actual code needed. Also the fiddle would require an image upload which honestly I do not know how to do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: By "that actually works", I mean that reproduces the issue... The code you provided doesnt achieve much... And you can link the url of the image, instead of trying to upload it

Comment: @Giovanni Silveira I edited the question, I uploaded the sprite image but still not working... It this good enough?

Comment: Ok, care to explain the use of that `:after` in there? And can you show an image or something of what is the expected behavior you want?

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira Just uploaded the images so you can see the effect. The images represent what is one with the hover and the active status. Once you are in the determined url the class active is inserted. Then I want the same image as :active inserted. So I added a.active:hover, but it doesn't respond. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Ok, so why are you using a background on `:after` instead of on the actual `a` tag?

Comment: And do you have a link for that menu? If not, can you reproduce the menu **exactly** in fiddle?

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira http://rosasusaeta.com/cepods/design-bar.php If you solve this I will give you +1 and the correct answer of course. I whtkn I will also learn a lot from this. Click on any category of the sub menu. Once inside any of these pages the background image should be done the same as the :active status

Comment: Either I dont understand what you asked, or you are missing something... It seems to do just what you are asking it to do right now

Comment: Oh ok, I see... the issue is with the submenus... Ok, let me take a look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so after looking at your site, the only thing you seem to be missing is to add `opacity: 0.9;` to `.sub-nav a:hover:after, .sub-nav a:active:after, .sub-nav a.active:after`

```
.sub-nav a:hover:after, .sub-nav a:active:after, .sub-nav a.active:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 6px;
    bottom: 2px;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Comment: Silviera How obvious... I thought it was being applied... Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Daniel no problem... we are here to help :)

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero: And just as a side note, now you know why I hate the usage of `:after` and `:before` unless absolutely necessary... There is hardly any decent methods for debugging those, since you dont really see the applicable CSS show up for those in debug.

Comment: Silviera Yep, in that point you are completely right. Even so, :before and :after give you the chance of using much less html markup. I suppose in the future you will be able to debug these parameters in a much more simple way. Thanks for the tip